# Add User Meta Data into Woo Account Page, but no param in do_action()

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

On the "My Account" page, I want to add custom fields. So I add functions into my functions.php in my theme with add_action.

1/

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_save_account_details', 'save_extra_user_profile_fields' );
function save_extra_user_profile_fields( $user_id ) 
{
     update_user_meta( $user_id, 'account_subscribe', ((!empty( $_POST['account_subscribe'] ))?"Y":"N") );
}
```

=> it works fine, because they send me $user_id as a parameter so I can update the DB.

BUT :

2)

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_edit_account_form_start', 'load_extra_user_profile_fields' );

function load_extra_user_profile_fields( $user )
{
   print_r($user)
}
```

I receive nothing as parameter in my function.

I have to play with /plugins/woocommerce/templates/myaccount/form-edit-account.php to add $user as a parameter

```
do_action( 'woocommerce_edit_account_form_start', $user )
```

but I don't like it because it will break at the next Woocommerce update.

So, here is my question today : I understand templates etc have a do_action() to hook treatments in the theme, and we code and call them with add_action(). But how do you catch values, vars , params etc without touching the remote plugin, if plugin developers didn't think to put them in the do_action() ? And how do you return them ?

Thank you very much by advance.

Comment: woocommerce_edit_account_form_start passes no parameters. You can use [wp_get_current_user()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_current_user/) inside your function.

Comment: Yes, but how do I return $user to the form ?